# RegExp match group not preceded by alphanumeric (\w) ignoring spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a group that only matches when the first non-spacing character preceding the match is NOT an alphanumeric character.

RegExp i've tried, consuming the spaces first with \s* then looking behind to check for \w:

```
(?<!\w)\s*\({\w+}\)
```

Success

```
Input:  this will = ({match})
Expected: ({match})
Actual: ({match})
```

Failure, still matches while preceded by alphanumeric (ignoring spaces)

```
Input:  this should = not ({match})
Expected: -
Actual: ({match})
```

Using \s+ instead of \s* solved it partially but now it requires at least one space which is not desired!

```
(?<!\w)\s+\({\w+}\)
```

I've been looking around the internet but cannot solve the problem. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this solution (a mix of [@horcrux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372088/regexp-match-group-not-preceded-by-alphanumeric-w-ignoring-spaces#comment117339978_66372088) and [@Wiktor Stribizew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372088/regexp-match-group-not-preceded-by-alphanumeric-w-ignoring-spaces#comment117340259_66372088) suggestions):

```php
<?php

$regex = '/(?<![\w\s])\s*(\({\w+}\))/';
$string = 'this will = ({match})
this should = not ({match})';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

?>
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/hD41IO/1).

**Results**:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "({match})"
}
```

See [PHP proof](https://tio.run/##RY3RCoMgGIXvfQoHQboNYte1@SAZIksysBJ/m4Po2Z1zG7s75zv/f47VNsaGWW0RKpwa1BNfcVkR1hxaHjh0lMORcLLxcNo5pVVZowK8G@fhfej1CDiMxiRDtkn6u94pyhT0spo@8Xnx/yy92zQjshXSGPJZPeNvaxI5U0Br9JBO9OtkyY@1ly5hxG4xvgA).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\s]                   any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                             \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

If there has to be a first non-spacing character present, you could match it and use `\K` to clear the match buffer.

```
[^\w\s]\h*\K\({\w+}\)
```

The pattern matches

- `[^\w\s]` Match a single char other than a word char or whitespace char
- `\h*\K` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars and forget what is matched so far
- `\({\w+}\)` Match 1+ word chars between `({` and `})`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PIgmnF/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/bpsLI)